# How to add a missing closing parenthesis to a string in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string, python-re

I have multiple strings to postprocess, where a lot of the acronyms have a missing closing bracket. Assume the string `text` below, but also assume that this type of missing bracket happens often.

My code below only works by adding the closing bracket to the missing acronym independently, but not to the full string/sentence. Any tips on how to do this efficiently, and preferably without needing to iterate ?

```
import re
 
#original string
text = "The dog walked (ABC in the park"

#Desired output:
desired_output = "The dog walked (ABC) in the park"


#My code: 
acronyms = re.findall(r'\([A-Z]*\)?', text)
for acronym in acronyms:
  if ')' not in acronym: #find those without a closing bracket ')'. 
    print(acronym + ')') #add the closing bracket ')'.

#current output:
>>'(ABC)'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
text = re.sub(r'(\([A-Z]+(?!\))\b)', r"\1)", text)
```

With this approach, you can also get rid of the check if the text has `)` in it before, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/tjwoSm/1).

---

In full:

```
import re
 
#original string
text = "The dog walked (ABC in the park"
text = re.sub(r'(\([A-Z]+(?!\))\b)', r"\1)", text)
print(text)
```

This yields

```
The dog walked (ABC) in the park
```

See [**a working demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/pKGIV7).

Comment: ahhh nice, this is exactly what I was looking for. So ```r"\1)"```  substitutes with a closing bracket ?

Answer (score 2):

For the typical example you have provided, I don't see the need of using `regex`
You can just use some string methods:

```py
text = "The dog walked (ABC in the park"
withoutClosing = [word for word in text.split() if word.startswith('(') and not word.endswith(')') ]
withoutClosing
Out[45]: ['(ABC']
```

Now you have the words without closing parenthesis, you can just replace them:

```py
for eachWord in withoutClosing:
    text = text.replace(eachWord, eachWord+')')
    
text
Out[46]: 'The dog walked (ABC) in the park'
```