# How to add a missing closing parenthesis to a string in R?

Tags: r, regex, string

I would like to add a closing parenthesis to strings that have an open parenthesis but are missing a closing parenthesis.
For instance, I would like to modify "The dog walked (ABC in the park" to be "The dog walked (ABC) in the park".

I found a similar question and solution but it is in Python ([How to add a missing closing parenthesis to a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67400960/how-to-add-a-missing-closing-parenthesis-to-a-string-in-python)). I have tried to modify the code to be used in R but to no avail. Can someone help me with this please?

I have tried modifying the original python solution as R doesn't recognise the "r" and "\" has been replaced by "\\" but this solution doesn't work properly and does not capture the string preceded before the bracket I would like to add:

```
text = "The dog walked (ABC in the park"
str_replace_all(text, '\\([A-Z]+(?!\\))\\b', '\\)') 
text
```

The python solution that works is as follows:

```
text = "The dog walked (ABC in the park"
text = re.sub(r'(\([A-Z]+(?!\))\b)', r"\1)", text)
print(text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
stringr::str_replace_all(text, '\\([A-Z]+(?!\\))\\b', '\\0\\)')
```

- output

```
"The dog walked (ABC) in the park"
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! How would it change if i wanted the output to be "The dog walked (ABC in the park)" instead?

Comment: If it is in end of your string , you may simply use `stringr::str_replace_all(text, '$', '\\0\\)') ` will give `"The dog walked (ABC in the park)"`

Comment: Ah i see, thank you for your prompt responses!!

Answer (score 2):

You might also use gsub, and first use the word boundary and then the negative lookahead.

In the replacement use the first capture group followed by `)`

```
text = "The dog walked (ABC in the park"
gsub('(\\([A-Z]+)\\b(?!\\))', '\\1\\)', text, perl=T)
```

Output

```
[1] "The dog walked (ABC) in the park"
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a one liner, but it does the trick and is (hopefully!) intuitive.

```
library(stringr)

add_brackets = function(text) {
    brackets = str_extract(text, "\\([:alpha:]+") # finds the open bracket and any following letters
    brackets_new = paste0(brackets, ")") # adds in the closing brackets
    str_replace(text, paste0("\\", brackets), brackets_new) # replaces the unclosed string with the closed one
}
```

```
> add_brackets(text)
[1] "The dog walked (ABC) in the park"
```