# How to add a missing closing parenthesis at a specific position to a string in R?

Tags: r, regex, string

I would like to **add a closing parenthesis to strings that have an open parenthesis but are missing a closing parenthesis.** For instance, I would like to modify "This is a (test) (1 testing two" to "This is a (test) (1 testing two)".

This solution comes close but I would like to place any missing closing parenthesis at the end of the string instead of after the number:

```
text = "This is a (test) (1 testing two"
str_replace_all(text, '\\([0-9]+(?!\\))\\b', '\\0\\)')
```

A similar question has been asked before here ([How to add a missing closing parenthesis to a string in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72950868/how-to-add-a-missing-closing-parenthesis-to-a-string-in-r)) but I have not been able to modify it successfully. Any help appreciated please, thanks!

Comment: If you're not tied to regular expressions, you can use str_count to count the number of open brackets and the number of closed brackets and then paste closed brackets equal to the result to the end of the string

Comment: How about using the regex to detect the mismatch, then just appending a bracket if necessary? Does it have to be an all-in-one regex solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)

text = "This is a (test) (1 testing two"
text1 = "Testing missing (parenthesis)"

c(text, text1) %>%  
   str_detect(., pattern = "\\([^)]*$")

#> [1]  TRUE FALSE

c(text, text1) %>%  
  ifelse(str_detect(., pattern = "\\([^)]*$"), paste0(., ")"), .) 

#> [1] "This is a (test) (1 testing two)" "Testing missing (parenthesis)"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>